# Are translations greenlet-safe in Django?

Tags: django, internationalization, gevent, gunicorn

After taking a look at Django's source code, I see that Django stores the active language in the current thread.

In `django.utils.translation.trans_real`:

```
_active = local()
...
def activate(language):
    """
    Fetches the translation object for a given tuple of application name and
    language and installs it as the current translation object for the current
    thread.
    """
    _active.value = translation(language)
```

This is all fine, but I'm not sure whether or not it's greenlet-safe ?  I'm running Django with gunicorn, configured to run "green" gevent workers.  Is `local()` monkey-patched by gevent?  Or is there a race-condition where a request might be served using another request's active language when using gevent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ok nevermind, I found the answer in [gevent's documentation](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.monkey.html): **thread-local storage is monkey-patched by gevent and becomes greenlet-local storage**. So everything should be safe.

Here's the details:

- gevent's `patch_thread()` function patches the `thread` and `threading` modules, including the patch to make thread-local storage become greenlet-local storage.
- gevent's `patch_all()` function calls `patch_thread()`.
- gunicorn calls gevent's `patch_all()` function when starting a gevent worker.